# read three columns from a text file using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

My input file (text.txt) includes three columns. First one is belongs to x-axis, second column represents y-axis and third column represents y-axis again. When i run my code, i get "x.append(float(line.split()[0])) IndexError: list index out of range". How can I fix that error?

**my code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("text.txt", "r") as data_file:
lines=data_file.readlines()
x=[]
y1=[]
y2=[]
counter=0
 for line in lines:
 if((line[0]!='#') and (line[0]!='@')):
 x.append(float(line.split()[0]))
 y1.append(float(line.split()[0]))
 y2.append(float(line.split()[1]))
 counter+=1
plt.plot(x, y1, y2)
plt.savefig("text.png", dpi=300)
```

**my text.txt:input**

```
# Carbon
# Gallium 
#
@ title 
@ xaxis  
1.00    2.12    14.51   
2.00    4.54    18.14
3.00    6.12    45.11
4.00    9.02    89.15
5.00    6.48    49.99
6.00    8.01    92.33
7.00    7.56    95.14
8.00    5.89    96.01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

because your data file contains empty lines. They may be at the end of the file.

You could fix it by including

```
for line in lines:
    if not line.strip(): continue
```

but instead of the code you posted, I would use [NumPy's genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to parse the file this way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = (line for line in f if not any(line.startswith(c) for c in '@#'))
    x, y1, y2 = np.genfromtxt(lines, dtype=None, unpack=True)

plt.plot(x, y1, x, y2)
plt.savefig("text2.png", dpi=300)
```

---

If you want to fix your original code with minimal changes, it might look something like this:

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    x = []
    y1 = []
    y2 = []
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip() or line.startswith('@') or line.startswith('#'): 
            continue
        row = line.split()
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y1.append(float(row[1]))
        y2.append(float(row[2]))

    plt.plot(x, y1, x, y2)
    plt.savefig("text.png", dpi=300)
```

---

Tip: `readlines()`
reads the entire file and returns a list of strings. This can require a lot of
memory if the file is large.  Therefore, never use `lines=data_file.readlines()` unless you really need the entire file converted into a list of strings. Otherwise, it requires less memory if you can process each line one-at-a-time using

```
for line in f:
```